# Instances of someone from the lower caste winning acknowledgement of Devtas for stopping Adharma or separately, stopping injustice from upper caste?

Tags: dharma, caste

I am wondering if there are any instances in Hindu Mythology where someone from the lower caste (Vaishya or Shudra) fought or stopped Adharma and was acknowledged by the Devtas for it?

Or

Any instances where someone from the lower caste (Vaishya or Shudra) rose up against injustice from the upper classes (Brahmins or Kshatriyas)?

P.S. I am not talking about instances like Lord Purshuram's story (since Kshatriyas were already a very empowered class and them committing atrocities on Brahmins or Brahmins vengeance for it does not really count) or Karna's story (who was not really from the lower caste). Looking for a genuine lower caste underdog doing something amazing.